# PHP - Execute select query and loop through results

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am developing a web service using PHP. I am having some trouble while executing the select query. This is the code I'm using.

DB_Functions.php

```
public function getCompanies() {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company");
    // check for successful store

    if ($result) {
        return mysql_fetch_array($result,true);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

GetCompanies.php

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$companies = array();
//$rows = $db->getCompanies();

while ($row = $db->getCompanies()) {
    echo $row['companyName'];
    $rowArr = array();
    $rowArr['CompanyName'] = $row['companyName'];
    $rowArr['CompanyID'] = $row['companyId'];
    //array_push($companies, $rowArr);
    $companies[] = $rowArr;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response=array("Companies"=>$companies);
$json = json_encode($response);
echo $json
?>
```

But the problem is in GetCompanies.php file the while loop is runs endless. The code appears to be ok. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because you're re-running the query every single time you call getCompaines()... Store the result outside of your loop and iterate over that.

Comment: Tried. But couldn't get to work. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_query`?  You shouldn't be.  Switch to MySQLi or PDO.  `mysql_query` is going to be removed from PHP very soon.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `while ($row = $db->getCompanies()) {` you are running the *entire* query over again and returning the 1st row each time.  `mysql_fetch_array` returns *one* row.

What you need to do is have `getCompanies()` loop over all the rows and return an array.

```
public function getCompanies() {    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company");
    // check for successful store

    if ($result) {
        $ret = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $ret[] = $row;
        }

        return $ret;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, `getCompanies()` will return you an array that you can just `foreach` over:

```
$rows = $db->getCompanies();
foreach($rows as $row){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop declaration to something like

```
foreach($rows as $row) {}
```

And as Pavlin said, move the function call to getCompanies() outside the loop.

Also, how about modifying the query to select a particular set of fields from the database and directly sending them as the response without doing any additional processing?

Comment: Returns the error " Illegal string offset 'companyName'"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing Select query without any condition(where clause). And since the company table has data it would always return true in the while loop  this makes the while loop an infinite loop. For while to work properly the condition should become false to exit the loop.
Its not a programming flaw its a logical one.

Comment: You should add where clause and select a specific type of dataset instead of fetching all.

Comment: You should move while loop inside the function and return data from there if its there else return false.

Answer (score 0):

The php docs have all the information you need. You're using the wrong function:

> mysqli_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric
>   array, or both

vs

> mysqli_fetch_all — Fetches all result rows as an associative array, a
>   numeric array, or both

Just change your return statement to
`return mysqli_fetch_all($result);`
or
`return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`
to get an associative array.

And of course, you need to move your `getCompanies` call outside of the loop.

**NOTE**
php `mysql_*` functions have been depricated since version 5.5.* and are going to be removed from the language soon. You should look into `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: This is only half of the solution.  `while ($row = $db->getCompanies()) {` would still be an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes. That would also require change, as I've already pointed out in the comments.

Comment: P.S. He's also using `mysql_query` in his question, he'd have to change to MySQLi.

Comment: So he is. Well, he shouldn't, it's about to be removed from php.